# Get Distance Between Two Points in GeoPandas

Tags: distance, geopandas

I have two points as below. I need to get the distance between them in meters.

```
POINT (80.99456 7.86795)
POINT (80.97454 7.872174)
```

How can this be done via GeoPandas?

Answer (score 26):

Your points are in a **lon, lat** coordinate system (EPSG:4326 or WGS 84). To calculate a distance in meters, you would need to either use the [Great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) or project them in a local coordinate system to approximate the distance with a good precision.

For Sri Lanka, you can use [EPSG:5234](https://epsg.io/5234) and in GeoPandas, you can use the distance function between two GeoDataFrames.

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd
pnt1 = Point(80.99456, 7.86795)
pnt2 = Point(80.97454, 7.872174)
points_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [pnt1, pnt2]}, crs='EPSG:4326')
points_df = points_df.to_crs('EPSG:5234')
points_df2 = points_df.shift() #We shift the dataframe by 1 to align pnt1 with pnt2
points_df.distance(points_df2)
```

The result should be 2261.92843 m

Comment: by using the Kandawala / Sri Lanka Grid - EPSG:5234 CRS it is obvious the knowledge and extent you are going to answer the Question. thank you.

Comment: When I try this I am getting a tuple returned 0 NaN 1 41148.927095 what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: To get this to work I had to add .iloc[1] to the end of points_df.distance(points_df2) to return the distance value between the 2 points.