# How calculate distance between two points measured in longitude and latitude

Tags: python

I have a dataframe where, columns with subscript 1 are starting points and with 2 are end points.
I want to find a difference in kilometers between them.
I tried following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412462/getting-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-longitude/43211266#43211266) however got an error

```
import mpu
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'lat1': [116.51172,116.51135,116.51135,116.51627,116.47186],
        'lon1': [39.92123,39.93883,39.93883,39.91034,39.91248],
        'lat2': [np.nan,116.51172,116.51135,116.51135,116.51627],
        'lon2': [np.nan,39.92123,39.93883,39.93883,39.91034]}  
  
# Create DataFrame  
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data)  


mpu.haversine_distance((df.lat1, df.lon1), (df.lat2, df.lon2))
```

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63722124/4800086

Comment: It says `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`.
Yes, I also looked that, but could not apply to my dataset (as I have columns, but in this example they have only two points)

Comment: Edit your question to provide [mre], incl. sample input (we are not going to type in your dataset) as well as full traceback you get.

Comment: @buran I added the reproducible example of my dataframe